# Tracking List Database

Tags: mysql

So I'm building watch list application where people can add stuff they watched and they can rate it and what not, entries get stored in database so they're shared between users.

But I came to realize that I have no idea how would I efficiently store user list data. Should I create new table that has every column with id connected to table with movies in database? That seems inefficient as user list could contain hundreds or thousands entries and to create for each a new column would be very taxing on querying and space I think. I'm new to SQL and I'm not sure how to proceed with my project, and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand you correctly, you have a list of users and list of movies. Each user may rate a movie.
so in that case, I would create a new table movie_rating with following structure:

---

|movie_id | user_id | rating | etc etc

---

To store watched movies:
create table **watched_movies**

---

|movie_id | user_id | etc etc

---

This will certainly create large number of records if there are many users. But don't worry MySQL isn't that bad :)

Comment: I get how to store ratings, I'm troubled how to store the list of what the user has watched if user has few hundred entries.

Comment: you mean you want to store the list of watched movies?
I would take that too in a simpler way. See the edited answer

Comment: Wow, a few hundreds of entries! I don't know if databases can handle that! Just kidding, databases are intended for such use. Even the simplest of household PC's can easily handle databases with 100.000's of records..

Comment: Thanks, since I have just started with mysql I wasn't sure how taxing it is, I think I know what to do now

Answer (score 0):

Start by studying the subject and it will be clear very soon.

You typically create a User database with Users, a Show database with Shows, and a Rating database with Ratings. 
The Rating database contains items with a reference to a user, a reference to a show, and a Rating score.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but how would I store what the user has watched? I mean that user can add to his "watch list" stuff that he watched or plans to watch and it shows when he opens that list, that list entries would correspond to "shows" table. That list should be pretty big so I'm not sure how to efficiently store it.

Comment: The create a watched table like the Rating table, with maybe a NULLable item for Rating.